# how to run a self-defined R function in linux shell command？

Tags: linux, r

I want to run a self-defined function in the R file with name "run.plot.R" on a remote HPC with linux.

I type the linux command :

```
R CMD run.plot.R
```

But it seems the function code is not read by R from the file yet.
How can I load the function file into R and then run it?

Comment: `R CMD BATCH run.plot.R` or `Rscript run.plot.R`?

Answer (score 1):

Three options are:

```
Rscript run.plot.R
```

or

```
R CMD BATCH run.plot.R
```

or use the `littler` app, see http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html

All three of these run in a non-interactive mode.

If you want to run interactively, either

```
R --file run.plot.R
```

or just start R via

```
R
```

then once R is running

```
source("run.plot.R")
```

However, all of the above assumes that `run.plot.R` contains function code **and** the R calls to run those R functions.

Finally, given the filename, whether any plots are or can b generated will depend on how  is running on the remote Linux servers, whether X is forwarding over the connection you are using, etc.

Comment: So, in the file "run.plot.R" I must define the run.plot() function and in the end of the script file I MUST call the run.plot() function, right? (currently I only defined the function in the .R file)

Answer (score 0):

I often use

```
R --vanilla -f <filename>
```

The `--vanilla` flag is used to ensure a consistent R environment among multiple users. Depending on your needs, you may or may not want to use it.